# Compare and reduce complex array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have a ``dataset which is an *array of objects* for some items in a database that has the details of how long it will take in `estimatedDays` for a specific item to be shipped:

```
items : [
    {
    id: '1'
    shippingMethods: [
        {
        id: 'STANDARD',
        estimatedDays: 3,
        },
        {
        id: 'TWODAY',
        estimatedDays: 2,
        },
        {
        id: 'NEXTDAY',
        estimatedDays: 1,
        },
    ]
    },
    {
    id: '2'
    // same shipping data as above but standard shipping will take 4 estimatedDays
    },
    {
    id: '3'
    // same shipping data as above but TWODAY shipping will take 3 estimatedDays
    },
]
```

I am wondering if there is a reduce function that could compare each `shippingMethod.id` in each item and return a new array back only where `shippingMethod.estimatedDays` is greatest compared to all items.

So the end array would be an array of objects with (in this case) 3 shipping methods: STANDARD, TWODAY, and NEXTDAY.

Comment: You can check my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the `reduce` method,

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var items = [
    {
    id: '1',
    shippingMethods: [
        {
        id: 'STANDARD',
        estimatedDays: 3
        },
        {
        id: 'TWODAY',
        estimatedDays: 2
        },
        {
        id: 'NEXTDAY',
        estimatedDays: 1
        },
    ]
    },
    {
    id: '2',
    shippingMethods: [
        {
        id: 'STANDARD',
        estimatedDays: 4
        },
        {
        id: 'TWODAY',
        estimatedDays: 2
        },
        {
        id: 'NEXTDAY',
        estimatedDays: 1
        },
    ]
    },
    {
    id: '3',
    shippingMethods: [
        {
        id: 'STANDARD',
        estimatedDays: 3
        },
        {
        id: 'TWODAY',
        estimatedDays: 3
        },
        {
        id: 'NEXTDAY',
        estimatedDays: 1
        },
    ]
    },
];

var outItems = items.reduce(function(accu, curr){
   if(curr.shippingMethods) {
      if(accu.length > 0) {
         for(var i = 0; i < curr.shippingMethods.length; i++) {
            var current = curr.shippingMethods[i];
            if(accu[i].id === current.id && accu[i].estimatedDays < current.estimatedDays) {
               accu[i] = current;
            }
         }
      } else {
         accu = curr.shippingMethods;
      }
   }
   
   return accu;
}, []);

console.log(outItems);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a more optimal way of doing it in your opinion?